# Update to SVD by changing 2 row vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have a matrix in the form

$\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 \\
B \\
c_1  
\end{bmatrix}
$

(The blocks of this matrix should be vertically stacked...don't know why the latex is wrong)

and its SVD is X.  Is there an efficient way of computing the SVD of

$
\begin{bmatrix}
a_2 \\
B \\
c_2  
\end{bmatrix}
$

Where I replace the first row vector and the last row vector with new values, but keep B?

Comment: An oddity of the software on this site is that sometimes TeX formatting doesn't work unless you enclose TeX in `backwards apostrophes` or whatever they're called.  I also changed "array" to "bmatrix" and took away the delimiters because "bmatrix" provides those.

Answer (score 1):

From Golub and Van Loan, *Matrix Computations* 3rd Edition, Section 12.5 ("updating the ULV decomposition":

> ...$O(n^3)$ flops are required to recompute the SVD of a matrix that has undergone a unit rank perturbation.

If you just need the nullspace, you can get away with the ULV decomposition (L=lower triangular, U and V as in SVD), otherwise I am afraid you are out of luck.

But, as usual, the next question is: what do you need the SVD for? Do you need only the larger/smaller singular triples, or the whole decomposition?

Comment: I am trying to compute a series of regressions.

regress Y on X1
regress Y on X2
regress Y on X3
...

I know that real regression algorithms use matrix factorizations to solve $(X^TX)^{-1}X^TY$.  And in my case, X2 only differs by X1 in 2 row vectors, and X3 differs by X2 in 2 row vectors, etc.  

Comment: Then you only need to update a pseudoinverse --- the SVD is overkill. You may compute the pseudoinverse using the QR factorization and update that. Check Golub and Van Loan, Section 12.5.1 for the updates, and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse for computing the pseudoinverse with a QR factorization.